# Msg 8152 String or binary data would be truncated

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert, create-table

I know this has been asked before, but none of the answers are fixing the issue, need another set of eyes. I'm trying to create a table and seed it with some values. I don't have any value constraints so I'm not sure why I'm getting the error I'm getting.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AvailableTime]
(
    [Id] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TimeString] [NCHAR] NOT NULL,
    [TimeValue] [NCHAR] NOT NULL,
    [CompanyId] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [CompanyName] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
    [LocationId] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [LocationName] [NVARCHAR] NOT NULL,
    [IsClaimed] [BIT] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_AvailableTime] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.AvailableTime (TimeString, TimeValue, CompanyId, CompanyName, 
                               LocationId, LocationName, IsClaimed) 
VALUES ('2019-01-07T00:00:00', '12:00 AM', 1, 'Company', 
        2, 'Inver Grove', 'FALSE');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never specify a `CHAR`, `VARCHAR`, `NCHAR` or `NVARCHAR` column (or variable, or parameter) **without** specifying an explicit **length**!

If you omit the specific length, in some cases you'll end up with variable or column of **exactly ONE character** of length! That's typically *NOT* what you want!

**ALSO:** why are you storing `TimeString` and `TimeValue` as `NCHAR`?? Doesn't make any sense - use the **most appropriate** datatype - and here, that would be `DATETIME2(n)` and `TIME`.

So define your table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AvailableTime]
(
    [Id] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TimeString] DATETIM2(0) NOT NULL,
    [TimeValue] TIME(0) NOT NULL,
    [CompanyId] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [CompanyName] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
    [LocationId] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [LocationName] [NVARCHAR](100) NOT NULL,
    [IsClaimed] [BIT] NOT NULL,
```

and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need declare the size of your `CHAR` & `VARCHAR` fields in the table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AvailableTime]
(
    [Id] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TimeString] [NCHAR](50)  NOT NULL,
    [TimeValue] [NCHAR](50)  NOT NULL,
    [CompanyId] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [CompanyName] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
    [LocationId] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [LocationName] [NVARCHAR](50) NOT NULL,
    [IsClaimed] [BIT] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_AvailableTime] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a error in insert query, mismatch types in last column.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.AvailableTime (TimeString, TimeValue, CompanyId, CompanyName, 
    LocationId, LocationName, IsClaimed)
  VALUES ('2019-01-07T00:00:00', '12:00 AM', 1, 'Company', 2, 'Inver Grove', 0);
```